# Retrieving rows based on a substring on PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
<?php
//$query = $_POST['query'];
$query = 'TI';

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productTbl WHERE productName = '$query%'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

My user would have to key in a certain string into a textbox from Android and POST to my PHP. On the PHP side, how do I retrieve the rows according to the POST-ed string, let say the string 'TI' ? I tried this, but it returns null.

Comment: your code is vulernabe to sql injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: thanks but that's not what asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LIKE:

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); //better to be safer
SELECT * FROM productTbl WHERE productName LIKE '$query%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productTbl WHERE productName LIKE '" . $query . "%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

for wildcards you have to use the like key word, something like:

```
<?php
//$query = $_POST['query'];
$query = 'TI';

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productTbl WHERE productName like '$query%'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```